# Sending an email still have an error using VB.Net

Tags: vb.net, email

I want to send an email when user click `btnSubmit`. My problem is when I click the `btnSubmit` it gives me error at `Catch ex As Exeption`. I'm using `Web Form.aspx.vb`

Here is my code

```
    Dim mail As MailMessage = New MailMessage

        mail.From = New MailAddress("example@gmail.com")
        mail.To.Add(New MailAddress("example@gmail.com"))
        mail.Subject = "TEST SUBJECT"
        mail.Body = "Test Message"


        mail.IsBodyHtml = True

        Dim client As SmtpClient = New SmtpClient("smtp.gmail.com", 587)
        client.EnableSsl = True
        Try
            client.Send(mail)
            MsgBox("Sending Email succeeded") 'Return True if there is nothing error while sending email.    
        Catch ex As Exception
            MsgBox("Sending Email failed. Please try again")
        End Try
```

Comment: At first glance this all looks about right to me regardless of mail provider.  Maybe you could update your question with a clear explanation of how this isn’t meeting your expectations.

Comment: @Hursey I have edited my question. hope you'll understand

Comment: If this is exchange or Office 365 you have to enable normal SMTP in the server settings first.

Comment: i even try to change send it to gmail instead of outlook. but it still give an error at `Catch ex As Exception`

Comment: What is the Exception (ex.Message)?

Comment: @JonathanWillcock `The SMTP server requires a secure connection or the client was not authenticated. The server response was: 5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at ` I got this error

Comment: Ouh I finally got the answer !